# npm 5.4.2 - removes '@' from scoped package names

Tags: node.js, npm

After updating to the latest version of npm [5.4.2], I've began getting this error -
`npm ERR! cb() never called!`

I know it is because of my scoped package name - it is removing the '@' symbol from the folder names when trying to do a `npm publish` or `npm pack`.

This path -
'C:\ProgramData\Git\ngx-menu\dist\savantly\ngx-menu.es5.js'

Should actually be this path -
'C:\ProgramData\Git\ngx-menu\dist\@savantly\ngx-menu.es5.js'

Using node version - v6.11.3

```
C:\ProgramData\Git\ngx-menu\dist>npm publish
(node:15212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\ProgramData\Git
\ngx-menu\dist\savantly\ngx-menu.es5.js'
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-28T19_34_50_601Z-debug.log

C:\ProgramData\Git\ngx-menu\dist>npm -v
5.4.2
```

Comment: Created an issue here for this - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with npm v5.4.0 - v5.4.2

I rolled back to v5.3.0 and it works fine again.

`npm i -g npm@5.3.0`